# Is it possible to offload function to graphic card?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gpu, intel, cilk

I have a C++ multithread application, and I want to get better performance and decrease the total CPU usage, by using the Intel HD Graphics.

I'm not using CILK. (The application is written in pure C++)

I read the follwoing link:
[How to offload computation to Intel(R) Graphics Technology](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-offload-computation-to-intelr-graphics-technology)

But didnt found a way to process written function or threads on the graphic card.

Is it possible ?
   Is there a way to use intel compiler in order to offload functions (or threads) into Intel HD Graphics ?

Thanks

Comment: Not implicitly (as far as I know). You have to manually code those parts yourself (using eg. CUDA or OpenCL or similar frameworks)

Comment: using CUDA or OpenCL means that I need to recode the functions I want to offload. I want to use the same code, and just to offload the function to the graphics card (by using intel compiler, as explained in the link I provided)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But it's not straightforward.

You can use CUDA, OpenCL or DirectCompute for what you want, however you need to write a parallel version of your function. Running a "sequential" function on a GPU is definitely not interesting. Parallelising the algorithm might be the hardest task, underlyings APIs are roughly similar.

I empathize on this:

- the code you have is made for (single-threaded) CPUs, so is sequential
- the code you want the GPU to run **need** to be parallel

I don't know of any tool able to parallelize an algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, But If I will use the GPU, I cant use more "cores" (the Processor cores + GPU cores) no ? (So sequential multithread application can run more threads simultaneously)...

Comment: GPU and CPU don't work the same. Usually splitting the same work between CPU and GPU is not worth, because for good parallel algorithms the GPU will be 1000x faster, and for higly sequential algorithms it won't even run on the GPU.

Comment: Note that you can still use GPU and CPU at the same, but you need to design your application for it, ie determine which part of you application will be accelerated in a GPU and letting the rest on the CPU.

Comment: That exactly what I need: run part (some threads) on the CPU and other threads on the GPU. (Note: I'm not using parallel algorithms). So according to the link I added, I cant find a way how to do this...

Comment: This is not possible. A GPU should do only very small tasks. Also, threads on a GPU are more or less synchronized, which means a traditional sequential algorithm (with conditions for example) will be very inefficient. Last but not least: you can't share memory (this might change in some years).

Comment: I just thought it will be nice to decrease the total CPU usage (results of "top" command) by offloading some tasks to the GPU